# Element always displays at top of the fragment screen. Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Element is always displaying at top of the screen. I tried different ways to fix but out of luck. I want to place element at any location of the screen. This is fragment screen.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="myapp.com.myapp1.fragments.AddPeopleFragment">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="159dp"
        android:text="three"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="167dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever noticed these lines of code ?

```
   "android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true""
```

if you want to use absolute layout, do not bother these code;

eg:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="myapp.com.myapp1.fragmants.FragmantAddPeople">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="159dp"
    android:text="three"

    android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="167dp" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

you can place the item(which in case is the button) anywhere by changing the dp Value of absoluteX and absoluteY;``

Comment: By the way, you opened a `FrameLayout` and closed a `ConstraintLayout`...

Comment: The alignParent attributes have no effect at all if you are not in a RelativeLayout, and the layout_editor attributes only affect the editor preview. You should do well handling the element position using marginStart/Left and marginTop